# Activity having static reference

Tags: android

I'm working on an exiting Android code written by someone else and it has several memory issues. One issue which i'm not able to understand is this. In the main Activity class it has a static method called getReference(). 
This method basically returns reference to a variable called **mThis**. Now, in **onCreate** method

```
class MyActivity extends Activity
 {
     private static MyActivity mThis;    
     public MyActivity getReference(){
           return mThis;
    }
     public onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
       mThis = this;
     }

    ...
}
```

Now in Content provider or class extending from Dialog class, it uses this static method to get reference to context.

I'm pretty sure this is not correct and is one of reason for memory leak. But is there a way to get the current context without actually passing the context object in every class. There is an application context but  i don't think it has any method to get the current context.

I can remove this method and then pass reference to context object to these classes. But is there any other way to fix this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I'm pretty sure this is not correct and is one of reason for memory leak.

Yes.

> But is there a way to get the current context without actually passing the context object in every class.

There is no "current context". Please supply a `Context` to any method that needs one. You will notice, for example, that much the of the Android SDK is set up this way.

Comment: the static reference always points to the last activity created, how can it leak memory?

Comment: @uval: That activity cannot be garbage-collected, even if the user leaves the app via BACK and the activity is destroyed, if that static reference is not nulled out.

Comment: @uval If Activity is recreated by Android in case of Memory crises, you are then holding wrong reference of Activity which was destroyed !!

Comment: @AkashKava yep. One should be careful never to reference Context statically. I'm not doing so since 2012..

Answer (score 0):

When creating a ContentResolver and Dialog the context is already passed in the constructors so I don't see the need for that method. What is the mThis being used for in the other classes?