# How can I pass a custom object from one activity to another using putExtra()

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have been trying to pass an `array` of objects from one activity to another. I have been searching around and it seems that your object must implement either `Parcelable` or `Serializable`. (Which doesn't make much sense to me. I dont know why you can just pass the object array into the `putExtra()`). I am not trying to pass in a specific int or String but an array of lets say people objects. But I have been having trouble. The object array that I want to pass in is an array of objects that contain a `bitmap` and a few strings. I have tried to have my object implement both Parcelable and Serializable but I keep on getting errors. This is an error I get when I implement Serializable. Anyone have any tips?

```
03-26 20:35:53.886: E/AndroidRuntime(30066): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 20:35:53.886: E/AndroidRuntime(30066): Process: com.example.test, PID:    30066
03-26 20:35:53.886: E/AndroidRuntime(30066): java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.example.test.Person)
03-26 20:35:53.886: E/AndroidRuntime(30066):    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1316)
03-26 20:35:53.886: E/AndroidRuntime(30066):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1264)
03-26 20:35:53.886: E/AndroidRuntime(30066):    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:618)
03-26 20:35:53.886: E/AndroidRuntime(30066):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1692)
03-26 20:35:53.886: E/AndroidRuntime(30066):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:636)
03-26 20:35:53.886: E/AndroidRuntime(30066):    at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:7414)
03-26 20:35:53.886: E/AndroidRuntime(30066):    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2289)
03-26 20:35:53.886: E/AndroidRuntime(30066):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1437)
03-26 20:35:53.886: E/AndroidRuntime(30066):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3511)
03-26 20:35:53.886: E/AndroidRuntime(30066):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3472)  
03-26 20:35:53.886: E/AndroidRuntime(30066):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3714)
03-26 20:35:53.886: E/AndroidRuntime(30066):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3682)
03-26 20:35:53.886: E/AndroidRuntime(30066):    at    com.example.test.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:54)
```

Comment: **"...object must implement either Parcelable or Serializable. (Which doesn't make much sense to me."** : It makes complete sense if you think about it. Using `startActivity(...)` isn't just for starting another `Activity` in your own app and may result in a 3rd-party app being started. As your objects exist in your own process you need to either serialize or parcel them in order to pass them out of your process into another.

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,secondAcitity.class);                                                                                                                            Bundle extras=new Bundle();                                                     

    YourObject mObject = new YourObject();                                              

    extras.putSerializable("tag",mObject)
    intent.putExtras(extras);
    startActivity(intent);
```

**YourObject**

```
 public class YourObject implements Serializable
    {
private String name;//generate your getters n setter
    }
```

**In secondActivity**

```
 YourObject receivedmObject = (YourObject ) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable(
            "tag");
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to pass around Bitmaps, or objects that contain bitmaps, much less Arrays of objects containing bitmaps.

From your crash logs it looks like your Person object also implements Parcelable (while implementing Serializable as well). Remove `implements Parcelable` and the error should go away.

My advice is for your Person object to only contain the URIs of your bitmap (weblink or local storage uri) and build the Bitmaps only as needed.

Comment: I am not sure why I am getting a Parcelable encountered IOException. I am not implementing my person class with Parcelable. I am implementing it with Serializable.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I always use a singleton to share custom object between two Activities. You can also use `Parcelable/Serializable`.

Singleton Example: 
http://pastebin.com/pBeB7FBv

In your first Activity,

```
SharedData sd = SharedData.getInstance();
sd.setObjectList(your_object_list);
```

In your second Activity,

```
SharedData sd = SharedData.getInstance();
ArrayList<Object> myObjList = new ArrayList<Object>;
myObjList = sd.getObjectList();
```

Wrote it in bare hand, so a little bit of tweaking may be needed.

Read more: http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/framework.html#3

Answer (score 0):

you can only pass an object between Intent which is either Parcelable or Serializable. [this](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/06/parcelable-how-to-do-that-in-android.html) is a good example

```
public class Student implements Parcelable{
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String grade;

    // Constructor
    public Student(String id, String name, String grade){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.grade = grade;
   }
   // Getter and setter methods
   .........
   .........

   // Parcelling part
   public Student(Parcel in){
       String[] data = new String[3];

       in.readStringArray(data);
       this.id = data[0];
       this.name = data[1];
       this.grade = data[2];
   }

   @Оverride
   public int describeContents(){
       return 0;
   }

   @Override
   public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
       dest.writeStringArray(new String[] {this.id,
                                           this.name,
                                           this.grade});
   }
   public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
       public Student createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
           return new Student(in); 
       }

       public Student[] newArray(int size) {
           return new Student[size];
       }
   };
}
```

change it according to your need. **remember** `CREATOR` should be define as `public static final Parcelable.Creator`.

Answer (score 0):

I am also a victim of transfer of object and gone through serializable, parcelable and use of Gson. Finally I succeded by using Eventbus.
To transfer a custom object between two activities "EventBus" can be useful.
To setup EventBus simply download the .jar from [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22de.greenrobot%22%20AND%20a%3A%22eventbus%22) and reference it in your Android Project.

In your SourceActivity

`Intent intent = new Intent(this,Destination.class);
 de.greenrobot.event.EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(your_Object_to_send);
 startActivity(Intent);`

In your DestinationActivity

`Object myObject = (Object)EventBus.getDefault().removeStickyEvent(Object.class)`

Notice that there is no need of complex stuff.
The Efficiency Comparison is done [here](http://www.stevenmarkford.com/passing-objects-between-android-activities/) by steven

Answer (score -1):

Use static keyword to access array.  Define array static where you implementing and call from other class with ClassName.array

Comment: That did in fact work. I would think this would be a hack around it. But works for the mean time.

Comment: This will work for now, but the problem with making memory-heavy members static is that they don't get cleaned up from the heap, causing memory leaks.

Comment: **"Use static keyword to access array."** : NEVER declare `public static` fields or methods in an `Activity` with the intention to access them from any other application component. Using this design philosophy in Android development will almost certainly cause problems.

Comment: @Squonk please provide some link or case where its really occurring.

Comment: @Crazy : Just go to the search box at the top of StackOverflow and anter "[android]static object in Activity" (without the quotes) and you'll get a lot of search results. In particular, see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947079/activity-having-static-reference and the answer from Commonsware which explains how a static reference can cause memory leaks as the `Activity` cannot be Garbage Collected. Most importantly, any `Activity` which isn't currently visible can be destroyed by the OS at any time causing an unpredictable state.