# How do I use context with SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Currently I use this way to get context:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Context context = MyApplication.getAppContext();
        sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
```

MyApplication class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static Context context;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MyApplication.context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return MyApplication.context;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to call a method in `MainActivity` from `MovieUpdatesService` class

`MainActivity` method:

```
public void checkNow() {
        new Thread(() -> {
            String site = null;
            if (sharedPref.contains("site")) //line 153
                site = sharedPref.getString("site", "Not available");

            //codes...

        }).run();
}
```

`MovieUpdatesService` class:

```
public class MovieUpdatesService extends JobService {

    //codes...

    public void doBackgroundWork(final JobParameters params) {
        if (jobCancelled)
            return;

        new MainActivity().checkNow();

        Log.d(TAG, "Job finished");
        jobFinished(params, false);
    }

    //codes...
}
```

I get NullPointerException when running and I think it has something to do with context

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.content.SharedPreferences.contains(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.tashila.movieupdates.MainActivity.lambda$checkNow$0(MainActivity.java:153)
```

How do I fix this?
I'm new to Android so I'm hoping for a simplified answer (:

Comment: `new MainActivity()` is an illegal call. You aren't allowed to instantiate an Activity like that (and expect everything to work). What you want to achieve doesn't require an Activity at all! Also, why are you creating a new thread in your JobService and why are you calling `jobFinished` before the job has finished?

Comment: @Zun Could you explain a way around this? Thanks.

Comment: "Stop doing pretty much all the things he mentioned" is a good way around this.

Comment: Just put the code that's inside your `new Thread(() -> {` in your JobService.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I used `MainActivity.getInstance().checkNow()` and it worked. I meant that kind of "way around this".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4947166/2413303

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `MainActivity`, `onCreate` is called when you `startActivity`. So, when you call `new MainActivity()`, `onCreate` not get called and `sharedPref` not intialized. I suggest you to move `sharePref` to a sigleton class that manage all of preferences in your app.

```
class AppPref {
  SharedPreferences sharedPref;
  private static AppPref instance;

  private AppPref(Context context) {
    sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  }

  static AppPref getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
      instance = new AppPref(context);
    }
    return context;
  }

  public void someMethod() {
    // ....
  }
}

// Somewhere in your app
AppPref.getInstance(context).someMethod()
```

Comment: I didn't exactly use this solution but I used `getInstance()` thing to call the method in `MainActivity` and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following way to solve this problem:

***MainActivity.java***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static MainActivity instance;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        instance = this;
    }

    public static MainActivity getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void myMethod() {
       // do something...
    }
)
```

***AnotherClass.java***

```
public Class AnotherClass() {
     // call this method
     MainActivity.getInstance().myMethod();
}
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47241833/10389123